# How to create my own Vector Drawble? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-vectordrawable

I need to use an icon of a contract on my app.

Usually, I'd create a new Vector Asset and lookup for an icon that might do the job.

Unfortunately, this time I couldn't find anything similar to my needs, so I want to create one!

I tried reading about the issue [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources) but it wasn't really helpful.

can someone tell me how to do that and what is that pathData?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create vector assets from SVG sources. If you want to create your own icon, you should probably use a graphics program that can export drawings as SVG. Inkscape for example is free and available for a lot of platforms.

When you have the SVG file, in AndroidStudio select File -> New -> Vector Asset. In the upcoming dialog, select Asset Type 'Local file' and then pick/enter the path to your SVG.

Comment: What should I do once I have the SVG file?

Comment: I extended my answer to explain how to continue when you have the SVG.

Answer (score 1):

You can download from the web / create by photoshop your own SVG files , once you have `.svg` file you can add it to your project by `right click on app > new > Vector Asset > Local file (SVG,PSD)` and use it as you normally use `android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"`

now a `pathData` is A path that represents the outline of a shape which can be filled or stroked. A path can also be used as a clipping path, to describe animation, or position text.

But for me what really did the job was just playing with the numbers of it and see the reaction of the actual path, what do i mean ?
Check out [ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) and watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2aq3ljlnQdI) , drag some `.svg` files from the web and start playing with it , I'm sure you will get the idea .